# How can I put my OnItemDataBound c# code in my code behind and bind it to the asp:repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

I'm a beginner in asp.net and it's my first time I encounter an asp repeater.
It's a repeater control in an .ascx page That I want to bind to a C# code

in the .ascx page :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="relatedFilesRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RelatedFilesRepeater_ItemDataBound">
      <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td width="30%">
                       <asp:Label ID="fileNameLabel" runat="server" />
                 </td>
                 <td>
                       <asp:ImageButton ID="signatureButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons/16x16/_Base Image/Symbol Check 2.png" />
                  </td>
             </tr>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

On top of my .ascx page I have declared my `OnItemDatabound` function in C# like so :

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
     void RelatedFilesRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
...
}
```

And it works well. But it's not aesthetic and clean to leave c# code in an .ascx
How can I put my `OnItemDataBound` function in my code behind and bind it with the asp repeater. Because I tried to simply copy paste my c# code in the code behind file and it's not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: it is ok to move this function to cs file, do this and explain what is not working and also show the header of .ascx file

Comment: I have some labels used in my .ascx page like fileNameLabel and fileName and they are not recognized in my code behind page. So I get errors when compiling.

Comment: You can't access those label directly. Reason is they are wrapped inside repeater so first you have to find the corrent repeater row then use row.findcontrol and give the ctrl id.

Comment: ok. but you didn't mentioned the row means parent of the ctrl.

Comment: protected void rptr_OnItemDataBound(object sender, e RepeaterItemEventArgs)
{
  Label label = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblExample");
 
}

Comment: Pz check the answer that i have just posted.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't access your label control is because it's inside of a repeater. Therefore in order to access them you can use `FindControl()`

```
var myLabel = (Label)FindControl("YouLabelId");
//Do Some Work
```

This will apply for the rest of your controls within the `<asp:Repeater />`

Further reading **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access those label directly. Reason is they are wrapped inside repeater so first you have to find the corrent repeater row then use row.findcontrol and give the ctrl id:

```
 void RelatedFilesRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
Label fileNameLabel= (Label)e.Item.FindControl("fileNameLabel");
ImageButton signatureButton= (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("signatureButton");
}
```